# How can I determine if the .Net 5 runtime is installed?

Tags: c#, .net-5

I installed .NET 5.0 preview SDK and runtime.

How do I detect/determine if the .Net 5 runtime is installed from in C# ?

Comment: Why do you want to detect .NET version?

Comment: Because 5 isn't a .NET Framework version; last. NET Framework is 4.8

Comment: Your usual way seems very suspect, however if you can explain what you are trying to achieve by this

Comment: I want to verify .NET 5 runtime is installed as I am using it's features

Comment: dotnet --version

Comment: @DurgaPrasad from c# code

Comment: Are the registry keys not there or do they have different values?

Comment: This GitHub issue addresses a similar concern for .NET Core 3.1 (direct predecessor of .NET 5); similar techniques can be applied to .NET 5: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1522

Comment: "*my usual of detecting the version by reading reg keys etc*". That description is kinda poor. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63445216/edit) the question and add a [mcve]

Comment: @Cleptus sure I removed that bit

Comment: @kofifus My suggestion was to add the registry reading code, not leaving your question a two liner.

Comment: How is this (I mean the post after being fixed with several edits) not focused? Voting to reopen. More context would certainly help, but this might be useful for future folks who want the exact same thing: detect if .NET 5 runtime prerequisite is on the target machine.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few things wrong here:

1. .NET 5 is **not** a version of .NET Framework, it is the next version of *.NET Core* ([source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/))
2. If your app is compiled against .NET 5, and the computer you're trying to run on does not have .NET 5 installed, then your app simply won't launch (think of it like trying to run an application compiled for .NET Framework 4.8 on a computer which only has .NET Framework 3.5 installed)*

And as .NET 5 is the next version of .NET Core, you can easily use the new (in Core 3.0) APIs

```cs
var netVersion = System.Environment.Version;
var runtimeVer = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription;
```

As mentioned in your original question, you are reading the registry keys for getting the .NET Framework versions (I'm assuming à la [so](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed)). Well the location for the keys that specify the .NET Core versions installed are located in a different place, namely `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions`. Here is how you could read them:

```cs
const string subkey = @"SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions";
var baseKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subkey);
if (baseKey.SubKeyCount == 0)
    return;

foreach (var platformKey in baseKey.GetSubKeyNames())
{
    using (var platform = baseKey.OpenSubKey(platformKey))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Platform: {platform.Name.Substring(platform.Name.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1)}");
        if (platform.SubKeyCount == 0)
            continue;

        var sharedHost = platform.OpenSubKey("sharedhost");
        foreach (var version in sharedHost.GetValueNames())
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-8}: {1}", version, sharedHost.GetValue(version));
    }
}
```

---

* Expect if you compile your application with `self-contained` which will bundle the runtime together with your app

Comment: I think this will return the SDK and runtime versions *running  the current process* - I think that's not what OP is interested in. The OP is asking how to detect if a version of Core SDK (v5 in the specified case) is present on the system.

Comment: I am not looking for .NET framework, I wanted to know programmatically if  ie".NET Runtime 5.0.0-preview.7" is installed

Comment: `and the computer you're trying to run on does not have .NET 5 installed, then your app simply won't launch` this is not correct, you can build a `self-contained` package that will bundle .net with the app.

Comment: @kofifus I updated my answer to include code to list all installed versions of .NET Core

Comment: @zaitsman that's correct, I'll update my answer with a side note that that is possible

Comment: @kofifus Framework != .NET Framework. .NET Core is a framework, but not *the* .NET Framework

Comment: @kofifus there's no confusion in the specs at all. .NET 5 is .NET Core 5, end of story. So the only way for your application to use .NET 5 features is to be built for .NET 5, just like any other .NET Core application. A better question would be how to detect the specific minor build, but **why do that**? .NET 5 is *not* an LTS version, so any microoptimizations will become obsolete in a year when .NET 6 comes out.

Comment: @kofifus you may want to use specific features until a Go-Live RC comes out in September. Again, you won't even be able to compile using newer features in an older Preview.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use the accepted answer! .NET 5 Core does not save anything to the registry any longer. I have .NET 5 installed and I have nothing in the registry at `SOFTWARE\dotnet`.

Also `RutimeEnvironment` and similar envir-based checks will show invalid results for "self-contained" applications that have the framework bundled into them.

The documented way to check the version is to launch `dotnet --info` or `dotnet --list-runtimes` and inspect the results. There's a million and then some ways to launch a console command and check the output.

Answer (score 2):

I am making an installer for a dotnet product, and one of my prerequisites is to install the dotnet 5.n.n runtime. I am testing all scenarios in few VMs, and here is what inconsistency I have found.

On the VM, the first time I started my test, there was no MS-NET product at all, so it was easy to determine this runtime absence through the registry key (HKLM/software/dotnet/...). However, when I install the runtime then uninstall it, the registry key did not get deleted (it was deleted on another VM by the way), so dotnet runtime check through the registry key returned true, but in fact, the runtime was not installed in the machine, I did uninstall it minute before. This was my 1st check.

So, what I did next (the 2nd check)? I did check the dotnet physical existence in the file system. That would be C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared or C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared location based on 32/64 bit installation. Note that these folders may contain one or more subfolder, and one that I was interested is this one:
Microsoft.NETCore.App -> holds core + not 5.n.n runtimes...

And the 3rd check is the registry installed/uninstalled key for the runtime: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{guid}

Answer (score 1):

As of 24 September 2021:
I needed to find out what version of Net 5 is installed. I updated my MS VS to the latest version, then created simple console .Net 5 app and got value from RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription. It was ".NET 5.0.10"

More information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Answer (score 0):

Open visual studio code.

Launch the Terminal from the Menu

Type the following command in the terminal window and read the version.

**dotnet --version**

Comment: Don't post images as links

Comment: @trentonftw - removed links. pls guide how to embed images in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can also check by running VS Installer and then going to the Modify section.

[image]