# How to best retrieve installed .NET Desktop Runtime versions?

Tags: c#, .net, version, .net-5, .net-6.0

I need to determine programmatically (c#) if a certain .NET Desktop Runtime version is installed on the system.

One option that I found was to check the version in the registry like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63445365) suggests. However, this will only retrieve the latest version installed. With ASP.NET Core versions can for example be found in the registry here: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET Core\Shared Framework

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription;`
Will only retrieve the version of the framework the application is running on.

The official way seems to be using the command "dotnet --list-runtimes" (documented by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows#check-runtime-versions)). This will require that a cmd process is started from the application.

Is there another possible way of retrieving the currently installed .NET Desktop Runtime versions?

Comment: What's your context? Are you checking to see if your app can be installed? If so, see [Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2019)  - re: instead of trying to figure out what's installed, it becomes a pre-requisite (that can be installed as part of the process)

Comment: I want to deploy and run a .NET Desktop Runtime 5.0.x executable only if no higher version already exists on the system. Should be possible without using MSI technology.

Comment: IMHO, you're  in "chicken or the egg".. In order to "find out what's in the system" you'll have to install "something" (_assuming it can be installed_ - how would you know - "hence chicken or egg"?) or have the user "do something themselves and let you know". From past experience, installer projects are "no pain" (for end users).

Comment: IOW, you write your app based on some version of .Net, which becomes a _pre-requisite_  (regardless). The installer msi will determine if the the version is available and _optionally_ download it if unavailable. Otherwise, you'll be, well, re-creating what that installer already does, or write different .Net versions of your app based on your "supported frameworks" (as a software provider) and have the user choose which one...

Comment: OR you self contain deploy the bootstrapper, and use that to detect and potentially install the runtime.

Comment: None of the solutions described in these comments are related to what I am trying to do. The question was just about if there are alternative ways of retrieving the currently installed .NET Desktop Runtime version on the system.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You probably don't need to know the runtime version at all. .NET 5 and 6 are .NET *Core* 5 and 6. They aren't stored in the same place .NET Framework runtime is stored, nor do they have to be installed *at all*. You can create a self-contained executable, even a single-file executable that contains all the libraries needed to run the application without installing the runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Not a great way but you can check if .NET install folders exist in the system. For .net runtime the install folder is -

> C:\program files\dotnet\shared{runtime-type}{version}\

Comment: Actually, [this is the officially recommended way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows#check-for-install-folders). The question is about .NET Core, not .NET Foundation, so checking the folder location is perfectly fine. It may not be necessary though, as .NET Core allows publishing self-contained applications